# Could an FPGA be connected via DMI to a processor, if so how would this be done?

Tags: fpga, interface, processor

Can an FPGA be connected to a processor via Direct Media Interface (DMI), without a dedicated Platform Controller Hub (PCH)? The FPGA would serve as the south bridge/ PCH. Along the lines of processors, I was thinking about the Intel LGA2011-3 ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it wouldn't be practical IMO. Electrically, DMI (at least of 2.0) was said to be treated electrically as PCIe Gen 2.0 by board designers / hardware engineers. So, any FPGA with transceivers fast enough (Cyclone IV GX or better, Artix-7 w/ 6.25Gbps GTPs or better) could probably chat electrically with the CPU.

That said, the impractical part comes from the fact that the details of the protocol and low-level behavior are likely in red-covered books at Intel that don't leave, unless you're a giant OEM (HP, Dell, etc.) or potentially a BIOS company (Phoenix, AMI).

Remember that the PCH also hosts the BIOS memory (SPI Flash) that the processor executes its first steps from, LPC bus, etc. There's a lot of low-level, trade secret type activity that goes on inside that chip (the PCH) in addition to its publicized functions. You'd need a large, fast FPGA (Virtex/Stratix++) to be able to pull this off, but again, I don't think it is practical.

Comment: Thanks, So you are saying that I could use an Artix 7 as a Southbridge, provided I were to have all of those low-level pieces of info, I would be able to implement a DMI connection between an intel CPU and the FPGA. What would I need to utilise an Artix 7 with DMI, information wise?

Comment: In all honesty, and to cover my ass, I will say that this is "practically impossible" (but not technically) for average folks like you or me. An Artix-7 would probably be too small; even if you picked up the biggest Virtex-7 part, you're basically looking to emulate a state-of-the-art ASIC knowing nothing about it. Technically it may have the speed and electrical hardware to not break anything if you attach it to the CPU, but I don't think this is a practical undertaking. Perhaps some state actors or large R&D companies could stand a chance at this.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you on that, its easier and cheaper to go with Intel's PCH and then attaching FPGA's via PCI-E to your CPU and finally using bus mastering if you want to use the FPGA's to do any controlling of other parts of the system.